# Can PyCharm sort methods alphabetically?

Tags: pycharm

I'd like my methods in classes sorted in Python files. I do wonder if PyCharm has such option (I couldn't find one).

Comment: This is registered in the developer [issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11870) - you can vote for the feature directly to original developers.

Comment: This is sort of a workaround, but if you have the Structure tab open, then you can view your method sorted in alphabetical order (there's an option). It won't change the actual order in your file, but it should help with navigation.

Comment: Thanks. I used the structure tab to sort the methods manually.

Answer (score 11):

Nowadays, there is [code blocks sorter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9450-code-blocks-sorter) which might help with this feature