# How to automatically sort functions in classes by their usage?

Tags: python, sorting, pycharm

**a)** The book Clean Code from Robert C. Martin suggests to sort functions according to the "step down rule":

> We want the code to read like a top-down narrative. We want every
> function to be followed by those at the next level of abstraction so
> that we can read the program, descending one level of abstraction at a
> time as we read down the list of functions. I call this The Step- down
> Rule.

**b)** PyCharm allows to show functions in **alphabetical** order in the Structure View. Also see [Can PyCharm sort methods alphabetically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45883520/can-pycharm-sort-methods-alphabetically)
Therefore, there is **no need to manually sort functions in alphabetical order** and I can use the order of functions in a class for a different purpose.

**c)** Until now I manually **sort them by their usage/abstraction-level/call stack**. (I also put static and public functions on top and functions starting with "_" below. I put properties below functions.) However, some colleagues in my team are not aware of that order or might follow a different order.

**d)** Instead of **manually** sorting functions by their usage/abstraction-level/call stack, I would prefer a tool similar to `black` (unfortunately, black [does not sort functions](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/3029)), doing that formatting/sorting work **automatically** for us on save actions. (The order of the corresponding unit-tests should be the same as the order of the functions.)

**=>** How can I achieve that in PyCharm? Is there some **code**/plugin I could start with, already knowing about the usage order/calling tree?

Comment: if `black` can do it set it as the Python formatter for VSC

Comment: Unfortunately, it cannot. I already use black with PyCharm.

Comment: why not write the formatter, or a new command, that does this, you will find it is not trivial to write, be aware of decorators, and local functions

Comment: Then the interim answer seems to be, that there is no tooling support for the "step down rule" because it would be too complex to implement. In that case it might make no sense following that rule ....  because the chances are high that the order will be lost anyway when working with multiple persons in a team (?)

Comment: JetBrains IntelliJ for Java supports this.

Comment: Martin is about 30 years out of date here, even given that this book is 15 years old. Given any modern IDE you can direct-access any function or method you like, without having to worry about what the whole source file looks like from the top to the bottom. Forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to actually rearranging the code, showing the **Call Hierarchy** (Ctrl + Alt + H in PyCharm) for **Callees** might be helpful.

The Call Hierarchy is available without starting the debugger (once the indexing has been finished).

In order to navigate to a called function, one can expand a called function and click on its first entry (="grand child") in the Call Hierarchy View.

(Navigation is of course also possible with Ctrl + click on a function inside the editor.)

[image]